# error on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi this is ROR beginner's question.
I have creat controller.rb and view hello.rhtml following the tutorial, but when I try to open localhost:3000/say/hello, it come up with with error: No route matches [GET] "/say/hello"

could any one advice please?

Comment: What tutorial? Could you post your routes file?

Comment: the tutorial is from Lynda.com, a bit old, might be 2008, the router.rb only got two roll: myapp::Application.routes.draw do. then end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to setup a route for that in your config/routes.rb file. 
For first try i would say use a script generator, enter on the command line as being in the project library > `rails g controller helloworld index`. This will create a route for itself, and a controller file.
After this script runs, there should be a line in your config/routes.rb

```
Cloud::Application.routes.draw do
  get "helloworld/index"
end
```

Then you need to enter `localhost:3000/helloworld/index` in your browser url bar. Then ( as default ) rails will render the view located in app/views/helloworld/index.*. If you want to change this behaviour, go to the helloworld controller.
For more info there is a useful guide: [ROUTING GUIDES](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: I have done that, and the router.rb is there. but still got the same message. any other thing I can try please?

Comment: 1. What is in your routes.rb ?
2. What have you entered in your browser url field ?

Comment: router.rb is myapp::Application.routes.draw do. then end. URL i put on browser is: http://localhost:3000/say/hello

Comment: Okay, i've modified my answer.

Comment: tried that, the error message is Hellowworld#index, find me ain app/views/helloworld/index.html.erb

Comment: That's not an errormessage. Thats actually the content witch was rendered from a view, witch is located in app/views/helloworld/index.* You can write in that file what you want, it will be an html.
Please take some time to study the whole rails framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a route definition so that the URL you are requesting gets mapped to an action in the controller you have created which would render hello.rhtml. Say your controller name is says_controller.rb (thats how Rails gives the filename). In that if you define and action hello which would by default render hello.rhtml, then the `fallback routes` which are defined in the routes.rb file at the end would make a request to `say/hello` to look for the `say_controller` and `hello` action, thus rendering hello.rhtml.

For detailed help you can refer to the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). There is a lot of helpful material and it is explained very well.

Comment: could you let me know what to do please.

Comment: Looks like you are missing even the default route definition in your routes.rb. Can you add match ':controller(/:action(/:id))' within the do-end blocks in the routes.rb and then check.

Comment: just try it and now got different message: Template is  missing, missing template say/hello

Comment: While rendering the action will look for the file in this path app/views/say/hello.rhtml. Is the present in this path ?

Comment: yes, it is. the content of hello.rhtml is Hello World. but still not showing on browser.

Answer (score 0):

I started developing RoR recently and the best practise I got was the tutorial @ rails for zombies and video's @ railscasts. I suggest you watch some / make some and you get a general idea how to get started :)

-edit- on this issue: You're trying to render the hello view from the say controller.
since routing is handled by default on :controller/:action, do you have a action called hello in say? No action means no route means no view rendered.

```
class SayController < ApplicationController

  def hello
    #do nothing or add some code
    logger.debug "I'm in the say controller, hello action!"
  end

end
```

This should get it to render the hello file. You might want to take a look at restful actions  / crud though, rails uses those by default.

Comment: Hi thanks for that, will try it after i finish the one I got from Lynda.com. is the one you suggest free or have to pay?

Comment: Its totally free :) There are some paid video's and paid tutorials, but if you're getting to know rails its great to try it for free and learn the basics. You can pay for advanced stuff if you want but to understand the MVC structure and how routing is handled in rails the free ones will do.

Comment: I've gone through the Lynda Rails tutorial myself.  It helped me a lot, but he's doing a lot of things in that tutorial that are kind of out dated.  I would suggest you go to http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ and check that out.  It's an excellent tutorial on Rails 3 and it's free.

Comment: thanks for that, I still can't make the hello world work on the browser, I have tried all the advice above. is that so hard, it just my first step on rails.

Comment: cool, it work now, so I am move forward now. would you mind give me the link that you suggest to study ruby on rails please